# Parsing GPS (GPGGA) leads to a strange behavior

Tags: c, linux, parsing, gps

I am not sure how to explain this.
I get the GPS data only every few times. Okay i see that I don't have fix GPS, maybe because the receiver is near the window. After some times I get an error. Is it because I ask every second, should I ask only every 2,3 seconds?

And this is the console output. xxxx.xxxx is my latitude and yyyyy.yyyy is my longitude.

```
$GPGGA,07222,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,072226.000,xxxx.x,,,,,,,,,,,,     
$GPGGA,072227.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.,,,,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,072228.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.yyyy,E,0,02,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,072229.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.yyyy,E,0,02,99.0,290.85,,,,, 
$GPGGA,072230.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.yyyy,E,0,02,99.0,290.85,M,48.0,M,*5, 
$GPGGA,072231.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.yyyy,E,0,02,99.0,290.85,M,48.0,M,*50, 
$GPGGA,072232.000,xxxx.xxxx,N,yyyyy.yyyy,E,0,02,99.0,290.85,M,48.0,M,*53,     
$GPGGA,07223,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,07223,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,07223,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
$GPGGA,07223,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
Error reading GPS from /dev/ttyO4!
```

Comment: The statement `gnss_buf[i] = malloc(sizeof(gnss_buf));` seems odd. That means each string in the array is `GPGGA_LENGTH * sizeof(char*)` bytes. ***If*** you want a fixed length, then why allocate dynamically in the first place, instead of using an array of arrays?

Comment: As for your problem, is it the "Error reading GPS from /dev/ttyO4!" message you mean? If so then there's a lot of code that we don't really need to see. To learn what the problem might be you should print out [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (preferably using e.g. [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string). But my guess is a *resource leak*, you never close the file descriptor anywhere.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I changed the gnss_buf to a 2d array. Now it is `char gnss_buf[14][14];` but it did not changned the problem. I get the error because the data lenght is -1 from the read function. My actuall problem is why do I get sometimes the gps data and sometimes not. Is my sample rate to hight? Even when I changed it to `sleep(5)` it did not matter. The problem comes periodically. Like 3 times i get the data and 5 times not and then again 3 times getting the data.

Comment: If a system call like `read` returns failure (typically `-1`) then you need to check *what* the error was, you can't just say "I got an unknown error", the error *is* known and you get it by using e.g. `errno`, `strerror` or `perror`. Also read the `read` manual page.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg with `perror("Error: ");` I get `Error: : Bad file descriptor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *guess* is that you have a resource exhaustion, you run out of file descriptors.

You open a file descriptor early in the function, but you never close it, and a process only have a certain number of available file descriptors. Once you run out of file descriptors you can't create new and your `open` call will fail and return `-1`, which is not a valid file descriptor and will give you errors later when you try to use it.

There are *two* things you need to do: The first is to actually *close* the file descriptor before you leave the function. The second is to check that `open` doesn't fail (which it might do for other reasons as well).

Comment: Okay my bad that I forgot to `close(fd);`. I check now the open function for an error too. But the data from gps is periodically empty. Maybe I just have a bad reception.